# Why is my constructor parameter private class member undefined at run-time?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, typescript, undefined, angular

I am running into an issue where my private class variable is undefined at run-time. The code is:

```
export class AdminRegistrationComponent {

    adminRegistrationForm:ControlGroup;
    usernameValidation:FormValidation;

    constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {

        this.usernameValidation = new FormValidation(AdminRegistrationValidations.username);

        this.adminRegistrationForm = fb.group({
            username: new Control("", this.usernameValidation.valid)
        });
    }

    submit() {
        console.log(this.adminRegistrationForm);
    }
}
```

and `FormValidation`:

```
export class FormValidation {

    constructor(private regex:RegExp) {
    }

    valid(control:Control):ValidationResult {

        if (this.regex.test(control.value)) {
            return null;
        }

        return {"valid”": true};
    }

    get():string {
        return this.regex.toString().slice(1, -1);
    }
}
```

The issue is when valid is called on this.usernameValidation the private regex variable in `FormValidation` is undefined at run-time (I have confirmed the right value is being passed in). I have read that in Angular2 there are conditions around dependency injection that need to be considered, but I can't get anything to work. Essentially I have tried listing the classes as `@Injectable`, among other similar things. The exact error I am getting is:

`EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`

Thanks

**Final Edit**

The answer as noted below was that my valid function needed to be an arrow function:

```
valid = (control:Control):ValidationResult => {

    if (this.regex.test(control.value)) {
        return null;
    }

    return {"valid”": true};
}
```

Comment: Answered in TypeScript FAQ: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-does-this-get-orphaned-in-my-instance-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> he private regex variable in FormValidation is undefined at run-time (I have confirmed the right value is being passed in).

Most likely `regex` is undefined:

```
constructor(private regex:RegExp) {
}
```

If not then `valid(control:Control):ValidationResult {` is being called with the wrong `this`. Fix use an arrow:

```
valid = (control:Control):ValidationResult => {

    if (this.regex.test(control.value)) {
        return null;
    }

    return {"valid”": true};
}
```

More on arrow functions : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Video [on `this` in TypeScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA)

Comment: regex was defined, changing the valid function to an arrow function did the trick. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with JavaScript itself. In fact, when referencing a function, you need to bind to an object to be able to use the `this` keyword.

Using the `bind` method should fix your problem:

```
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {
  this.usernameValidation = new FormValidation(
              AdminRegistrationValidations.username);

  this.adminRegistrationForm = fb.group({
    username: new Control("", 
        this.usernameValidation.valid.bind(this.usernameValidation)
  });
}
```

Comment: Minor: bind is slightly unsafe in TypeScript at the moment https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html Better to put an arrow